# Why is the default aspx called?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mysql, web-applications

I'm a new programmer trying to understand someone else's code. The program's purpose is to put MySQL data into a word file template using bookmarks. AR and ICN are 2 types of reports, thus they each have their own template. The code was originally containing only AR's, I have now added ICN. The console application works well, I have problems with the Web page. I don't understand why the `if (int.TryParse(ticketId, out currentTicket))` in my code is `FALSE` which generates a default.aspx .

**Trying to view in broswer this code**

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using TicketExtractionLibrary;

namespace TicketExtractionWeb
{
    public partial class GetAR : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ticketId = Request.QueryString["TicketId"];
            int currentTicket;

            string applicationPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;
            ARExtractionController ARController = new ARExtractionController();

            string arTemplateLocation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/AR.dot");
            string mappingLocation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ARmapping.xml");

            if (int.TryParse(ticketId, out currentTicket))
            {
                ARController.Extract(currentTicket, applicationPath + "LastTickets", arTemplateLocation, mappingLocation);

                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
                Response.AddHeader("content-transfer-encoding", "binary");
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=AR" + ticketId + ".docx");

                Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);

                string path = Server.MapPath(@"\LastTickets\AR" + ticketId + ".docx");
                System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);

                Response.WriteFile(path);

                Response.End();
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Solution Explorer]

Comment: Check the value of Request.QueryString["TicketId"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is saying, if the TicketID passed via the querystring is not an integer, then there is no report or Word document to generate, therefore redirect the user to the default.aspx page.

Comment: ah, it's true. I should have googled int.tryparse before asking this question. Should I delete it?

Comment: No, even elementary questions should show up in SO.  Somebody else may come up with a similar question and it would be good to find your question with its answers.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the TicketID must no be integer due to which TryParse is returning FALSE and you are redirected to default page. Ensure that TicketID value is integer.

Answer (score 0):

As @MarkSherretta says, the TryParse fails, which sends a "false" to the "if" statement, causing control to pass to the "else", which calls Default.aspx, as your code indicates.

See MSDN on TryParse:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx